# Can't connect esp8266 via USB to Linux Mint 21.1

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, linux

## What was my problem

I had a big problem with my esp8266. I couldn't upload anything to it using the Arduino IDE 2.2.1, the ttyUSB port couldn't be found.

When I plug my esp8266 into the USB Port, it shows up in the port selection in the Arduino IDE but then disappears imminently.

### dmesg | grep ch34

```bash
[    7.286317] usbcore: registered new interface driver ch341
[    7.286328] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for ch341-uart
[    7.286342] ch341 1-3:1.0: ch341-uart converter detected
[    7.304530] usb 1-3: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[    7.804730] usb 1-3: usbfs: interface 0 claimed by ch341 while 'brltty' sets config #1
[    7.811803] ch341-uart ttyUSB0: ch341-uart converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[    7.811814] ch341 1-3:1.0: device disconnected
```

As shown above, the esp8266 is connecting, but then disconnects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The solution

https://www.linux.org/threads/ch340-driver-on-linux-mint.44961/post-204493

`sudo apt-get remove -y brltty`

Just remove the brltty package.

### What is brltty?

https://brltty.app/ 
"BRLTTY is a background process (daemon) which provides access to the Linux/Unix console (when in text mode) for a blind person using a refreshable braille display. It drives the braille display, and provides complete screen review functionality. Some speech capability has also been incorporated."

So as long as you don't need the abilty for displaying something on a braille display, you'll good to go wit that solution.

I hope, that this will help anyone :D I posted this here, because I was searching for that very long, so it might be useful to have short solution for that.